# Android: Pipe channels

Tags: java, android

How can i use a pipe channel to open and read a file on android? Can anyone give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

use the standard java File and FileInput/OutputStream classes.  To get a handle on locations you can use a Context reference

```
mContext.getCacheDir();
mContext.getFilesDir();
Enviroment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```